# Excel Userform VBA VLOOKUP from intranet file (2)

Tags: vba, excel

Following up from my previous post (of same title). I have a user form from which I need to look up data based on a list of items in a drop down box "XXXXList". The VBA code works partially. The code is able to look for and open the right file from the intranet called "database". But once the file is opened, I get the following error message "Automation error".

The code i have is:

```
Private Sub ContractsList_AfterUpdate()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

' set workbook to workbook location at internet

Set WB = Workbooks.Open("https://Private.Private.Private.uk/Private/Private/Private/Private/Private.xlsm")
Set Sht = WB.Worksheets("Availabledata")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Workbooks("database.xlsm").Close

With Me.XXXXList
    'value to be found in Column H of 3rd worhseet
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Sht.Range("H:H"), 0)) Then
        'Lookup values based on first control
        Me.TextBox1 = Sht.Range("H" & Application.Match(.Value, Sheet3.Range("H9:H100"), 2)).Value '<-- value not found in Column H
    Else
        MsgBox "This contract is not on the list"
        .Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Also, the worksheet "database.xlsm" is meant to flash open for a second and then close immediately, but instead it asks me if I want to save the data.

I don't want really want that, is it possible to skip that step and close it automatically?

Comment: When you debug the code, is any particular line highlighted? Also what is the role of VLOOKUP in all this? Are you just trying to open an excel workbook so that VLOOKUPed data is updated in another workbook?

Comment: The line highlighted is "If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Sht.Range("H:H"), 0)) Then" . One part of the code opens and closes the file that's in the intranet and the other is a vlookup from a userform dropdown list called "xxxx.List" that is the lookup value and is meant to return the data of the 3rd worksheet called "database" of column I. Table area is column H. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here - you open a file "Private.xlsm" and then close a different file "database.xlsm" ?  What are each of these files?

Comment: The file to be opened and closed is called database, I have changed our link to the intranet to private/private... for privacy reasons. Shall I elaborate more?

Comment: Is my explanation still unclear? Shall i edit my post totally and try again?

Comment: It would help to make your code consistent.  If "Private.xlsm" and then  "database.xlsm" are the same file then why are you closing it *before* trying to read data from the sheet?  It needs to be open for that to work.

Comment: The debug error "type mismatch" is on line:  "Me.TextBox1 = Sht.Range("H" & Application.Match(.Value, Sheet3.Range("H9:H100"), 2)).Value"